# USB connectors dont recognize device but works

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, port

I have a `logitech` mouse. This mouse was working on every USB-port. But it stopped working on one by one and now I'm able to use it as a `normal` mouse. But its not recognized with a `Logicool` app anymore - so I can't set button functionality etc...
Is there a way to `reset` usb ports or something like that, without reinstalling windows?
[driver screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwnyq.png)

Comment: Seems like a hardware error on the mouse or the USB ports. Try another Logitech mouse to see if it behaves better.

Comment: mouse works on another pc, but i dont have another mouse to test it